# Grouping in SQL Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still new to SQL and my question here is kinda long. Ok here it is...my task is to calculate the total downtime of machines situated in a particular location. Each machine has parent, children and grandchildren. For eg:

```
Location:A1
Machine no:A1-100, A1-100-01, A1-100-01-001, A1-200, A1-200-01
(A1-100-01, A1-100-01-001 belongs to A1-100) and (A1-200-01 belongs to A1-200)
```

This is my SQL query:
`select machine_no, downtime from table_name where location='A1'`

The output is:

```
machine_no       downtime
A1-100-01           2
A1-100              1.5
A1-200              3
A1-100-01-001       0.5
A2-200-01           1.5
```

My question is how do I group the children and grandchildren to their parent and display the total downtime of that group? I'm sorry if the question is confusing but basically I want the output to be like this:

```
machine_no         total_downtime
A1-100                   4        (total of A1-100,A1-100-01,A1-100-01-001)
A1-200                   4.5      (total of A1-200,A1-200-01)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following query:

```
SELECT machine_no, SUM(downtime) as total_downtime
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
         SUBSTR(machine_no, 1,
             CASE WHEN INSTR(machine_no, '-', 1, 2) = 0 THEN LENGTH(machine_no) ELSE INSTR(machine_no, '-', 1, 2)-1 END
             ) as machine_no, -- this will get the part of machine_no before the second '-' char
         downtime 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE location='A1'
) InnerQuery
GROUP BY machine_no
```

output:

```
 machine_no    total_downtime
 A1-100        4    
 A1-200        4.5
```

You don't actually need the inner query, but it's more readable then grouping by the SUBSTR(....) expression.

[Play with it yourself on sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c000/17)

Comment: Thank you very much =)...but it stated invalid table name due to the select expression

Comment: see my edited answer. btw, this will work on sql server, but probably not work on oracle or mysql. next time you ask a question on sql, be sure to tag it with the correct database type.

Comment: Still got error. This time it stated invalid column name. Maybe I did careless mistake somewhere ;)...will check again...thank you so much for you help..really appreaciate it =)...

Comment: yeah, sorry. I forgot to type Oracle there.

Comment: I'm basically an sql server guy myself, but I think this last edit should work on Oracle database.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this part "as machine_no, downtime"..do I have to rename the machine_no

Comment: the part `as machine_no` gives the part before it (the `LEFT(...)`) a name so that you can use it in the resultset (in this case, in the outer query). it's called [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), and it's a basic part of SQL.

Comment: I still couldn't excute it. Not sure where I did wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's my fault. I must have looked on the wrong documentation. 
Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I have another question though. I have dates of the downtime from another table (Table_2). I want to display the machine_no, total_downtime and the month. To change it to month i used to_char(date,'MM'). I'm having problem to join these 2 tables. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad i could help. I suggest you ask a new question, you will have a better chance of getting faster help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` along with `sum` like :

```
select machine_no, sum(downtime) from table_name where location like 'A1-100%' group by machine_no;
```